# What would be the cardinality between Artist vs ArtWork vs Group?

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

> You set up a database company, ArtBase, that builds a product for art galleries. The core of this product is a database with a schema
>   that captures all the information that galleries need to maintain.
>
> Galleries keep information about artists, their names (which are
>   unique), birthplaces, age, and style of art.
>
> For each piece of artwork, the artist, the year it was made, its
>   unique title, its type of art (e.g., painting, lithograph, sculpture,
>   photograph), and its price must be stored.
>
> Pieces of artwork are also classified into groups of various kinds,
>   for example, portraits, still lifes, works by Picasso, or works of the
>   19th century; a given piece may belong to more than one group. Each
>   group is identified by a name (like those just given) that describes
>   the group.
>
> Finally, galleries keep information about customers. For each
>   customer, galleries keep that person’s unique name, address, total
>   amount of dollars spent in the gallery (very important!), and the
>   artists and groups of art that the customer tends to like.
>
> Draw the ER diagram for the database.

Is the following ERD correct?

[image]

Is it possible that a group has zero Artworks?

Is it possible that the Artist didn't produce any artwork but still sits in the database?

Answer (score 0):

1) You used ID as a PK in Artist and Artwork.  This is a good thing as the use of an unique name (as requested in the business model) is wrong: after all, two pieces of art or two artists may bear the same name.  However, you did respect the business model for the Customer entity whose PK is Name.

You can choose to make a good ERD and use ID as a surrogate PK for Artwork, Artist, and Customer; or respect the business model you were given and use Name as a PK for these three entities. Personally, I'd go with the former.

The following two questions can't be answered given the business model only; the answers below reflect the cardinality in the specific ERD you designed.

2) Yes, because according to the ERD a Group includes from 0 to N Artworks;

3) Yes, because according to the ERD although an Artist makes from 1 to N Artworks (and therefore there wouldn't be the need to insert an Artist in the database if he didn't do any Artwork) there is still a relationship between Customer and Artist in the sense that a Customer likes from 1 to N Artists.
Therefore an Artist can be in the database even if he didn't produce any Artwork (yet), provided that he is liked by at least one Customer.  If an Artist didn't do any Artwork and is not liked by any Customer, he won't be in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some context information here, especialy some cadinality information. Pay attention to yourself asking questions about the context:

> Is it possible that a group has zero Artworks?
>
> Is it possible that the Artist didn't produce any artwork but still
>   sits in the database?

This information should be given by you (or by the presenting problem). If this is a work of your course or your college, your instructor needs to better explain the present context. If you are already working as a DBA or data modeler, please look for more information about this problem. It's almost indescribable the importance of a context in the development of an ER-Diagram. Keep this in mind: Without a well-defined context, the problem (the situation) is uncertain, and so is missing information to complete the reflection of a real-world situation. In short:

```
No complete context, no diagram (without a diagram, there is no system!).
```

I will make this diagram with you step-by-step, but I'll take some assumptions due to lack of information (context) here. I will give my opinion on certain resources used in ER-Diagram, but that does not mean that I'm saying you're layman. I am just showing my thought, which shows how I learned that here in my country. I believe that you are as capable as I am, ok? Well, let's begin...

---

Entities in ER-Diagram are defined when we have attributes / properties. According to your description, we can see immediately 3 entities here:

1. Customers
2. Artists
3. Artworks

Relationships exists to express links between entities. The most obvious relationship here is between Artists and Artworks, Don't you agree?

> For each piece of artwork, the artist...

In accordance with the context revealed, all artwork has a unique artist (always), but it is uncertain if an artist always has one, multiple, or zero artworks. I SUPPOSE that an artist can have many or no artwork. That being said, we see that artists to artworks have a cardinality 0 to N, because, again, an artist may have made several or no artwork at all.

So far we have defined three entities, and linked two of them. Let's continue...

> ...its type of art (e.g., painting, lithograph, sculpture, photograph)...

If an artwork has only a single type of art, and an art type is defined only by its name, then we have here what is called a Functional Redundancy (translated from the Portuguese term "Redundância Funcional"). In spit summary, Functional Redundancies are like relationships between two entities, and serve to save you the trouble of repeating the same field in multiple columns in a table (which would be susceptible to errors). In a Conceptual Model, they are represented as a field in an entity with the suffix "(R)" (without the double-quotes).

If an entity has a field (column) like a Functional Redundancy, but with different values (multiple), then we have what is called Multivalued Field (also translated from the Portuguese term "Campo Multivalorado"). These are fields in entities that have the suffix "*" (also without the double-quotes).

This is not the case of the type of artwork, but it would until now for the groups of each artwork:

> Pieces of artwork are also classified into groups of various kinds,
>   for example, portraits, still lifes, works by Picasso, or works of the
>   19th century; a given piece may belong to more than one group.

This would be true if groups only possess names, and no other entity relate to them. But then you said:

> and groups of art that the customer tends to like.

This has changed things a bit. Groups no longer is a Multivalued Field in Artworks entity and becomes an entity with two relationships, one for Customers and one for Artworks. The relationship between Groups and Customers reveals the preferred art groups by customers. The relationship between groups and artworks shows which art groups a artwork is related. Now let's talk about the cardinalities of these relationships.

> - ...a given piece may belong to more than one group. [...]
> - ...and groups of art that the customer tends to like. [...]

Concerning Groups and Artworks, the word "may" says a lot to me. It says that something may or may not be effective. Still, it is uncertain whether an artwork can exist without at least one related group. Because of this, I see a 1 to N relationship from Artworks to Groups.

Conversely, the opposite process is not clear. I believe that there may be groups unrelated to artworks, perhaps because they are new groups created in a given time. So I see a relationship of 0 to N from Groups to Artworks.

Let's talk about Groups and Customers. It seems to me that a customer like at least one group of art. So I see a 1 to N relationship from Customers to Groups.On the opposite side, as already said, it would be possible to add new groups without automatically tying at least one customer to it. I think there may be new groups unrelated to customers. So guess what? We have a relationship of 0 to N from Customers to Groups.

So far we have identified another entity, a Functional Redundancy, 
and two relationships with their respective cardinalities. Let's keep going...

> and the artists ... that the customer tends to like.

There is a close connection here between two entities, Customers, and Artists. This relationship tells us what artists the customers like. If a customer must like at least one artist, then we have a 1 to N relationship from Customers to Artists. If a customer may or may not like an artist, then we have a relationship 0 to N.

If an artist has zero or more customers who appreciate it, then we have a relationship 0 to N from Artists to Customers. If an artist has at least one client who appreciates it's work, then we have a 1 to N relationship from Artists to Customers.

Lastly...

> Galleries keep information about artists, [...] and style of art.

If multiple artists can share a single same art style, then we have a Functional Redundancy here. If several artists have various art styles, then we have a Multivalued Field.

After much talk, I came up with an ER-Diagram presented by your context and assumptions made by me:

[image]

**NOTE: The green points highlights major assumptions.**

Is this right? Is this the correct diagram? The correct answer would be (from me to you):

I do not know...

Without a concrete context, we can not finalize a diagram correctly. My tip is that you finish your context. Only then you will have a correct diagram.

Oh, one more thing. What would be this "money spent" attribute? If customers can buy artworks, it would represent a new relationship between Artworks and Customers. This relationship would represent the purchase of artworks from customers (called "ORDERS", for instance). If not so, skip this paragraph.

If I have forgotten something, please say so. If you have questions feel free to ask, I'm here to help you.